# R - How can I extract the exactly object from dataframe by dataframe's name?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to get a column of dataframe that has 3305708 obs. But, I have to consider that I do not know the name of the column and I'll access it by index*. Like this:

```
column_name <- names(df)[index]
column <- df[, column_name]
```

So, what is my problem? My problem is: in `df` I have many columns (consider 1 to 1000) and the columns does not have the same type of data. When I run the above code, the type of `column` is different of the type of `df$column_name_dataframe`. For example: consider a dataframe called `df` with 3 columns called `column_1, column_2, column_3`. The type of `column_1` is `character`. If I run `x <- df$column_1`, the type of `x` will be `character`. But, if I do this:

```
name <- names(df)[1]
x <- df[, name]
```

The type of `x` will be `list`.

How can I solve this problem? I want to get the same type of data.

*Index can be, in my case, a number between 1 and 1000.

Output of `dput(head(df, 1))` :

Please, remember that my dataframe has 3,305,708 obs, it is too many data and too many columns, 1000 columns. Below is a sample first row:

```
dput(head(df, 1)):

structure(list(st_acidente_feriado = NA_character_, ds_agente_causador = "VEICULO, NIC", 
ano_cat = 2013L, ds_cnae_classe_cat = "Atividades de teleatendimento", 
dt_acidente = "26/04/2013", st_dia_semana_acidente = "sex", 
ds_emitente_cat = "Empregador", hora_acidente = "1630", idade_cat = 47L, 
cd_indica_obito = "N", nm_municipio = "São Vicente", nome_uf = "São Paulo", 
ds_natureza_lesao = "CONTUSAO, ESMAGAMENTO (SUPERFICIE CUTANEA I", 
ds_cbo = "Operador de telemarketing receptivo", ds_parte_corpo_atingida = "DEDO", 
cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat = "Feminino", ds_tipo_acidente = "Trajeto", 
ds_tipo_local_acidente = "OUTROS"), .Names = c("st_acidente_feriado", 
"ds_agente_causador", "ano_cat", "ds_cnae_classe_cat", "dt_acidente", 
"st_dia_semana_acidente", "ds_emitente_cat", "hora_acidente", 
"idade_cat", "cd_indica_obito", "nm_municipio", "nome_uf", "ds_natureza_lesao", 
"ds_cbo", "ds_parte_corpo_atingida", "cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat", 
"ds_tipo_acidente", "ds_tipo_local_acidente"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


str(df):

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3305708 obs. of  18 variables:
$ st_acidente_feriado       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
$ ds_agente_causador        : chr  "VEICULO, NIC" "VEICULO, NIC" ...
$ ano_cat                   : int  2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 ...
$ ds_cnae_classe_cat        : chr  "Atividades de teleatendimento" ...
$ dt_acidente               : chr  "26/04/2013" "26/04/2013" ...
$ st_dia_semana_acidente    : chr  "sex" "sex" "sex" "sex" ...
$ ds_emitente_cat           : chr  "Empregador" "Empregador" ...
$ hora_acidente             : chr  "1630" "1940" "0400" "1040" ...
$ idade_cat                 : int  47 49 47 22 57 40 57 21 35 33 ...
$ cd_indica_obito           : chr  "N" "N" "N" "N" ...
$ nm_municipio              : chr  "São Vicente" "São Paulo" ...
$ nome_uf                   : chr  "São Paulo" "São Paulo" ...
$ ds_natureza_lesao         : chr  "CONTUSAO, ESMAGAMENTO  ...
$ ds_cbo                    : chr  "Operador de telemarketing" ...
$ ds_parte_corpo_atingida   : chr  "DEDO" "DEDO" "DEDO" ...
$ cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat: chr  "Feminino" "Masculino" ...
$ ds_tipo_acidente          : chr  "Trajeto" "Típico" "Típico" ...
$ ds_tipo_local_acidente    : chr  "OUTROS" "EMPREGADORA" ...
- attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
.. ..$ cols   :List of 18
.. ..$ st_acidente_feriado       : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_agente_causador        : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ano_cat                   : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_cnae_classe_cat        : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ dt_acidente               : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ st_dia_semana_acidente    : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_emitente_cat           : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ hora_acidente             : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ idade_cat                 : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
.. ..$ cd_indica_obito           : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ nm_municipio              : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ nome_uf                   : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_natureza_lesao         : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_cbo                    : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_parte_corpo_atingida   : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat: list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_tipo_acidente          : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
.. ..$ ds_tipo_local_acidente    : list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
..    $ default: list()
.. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

Output of `dput(head(df, 10))` :

Please, remember that my dataframe has 3,305,708 obs, it is too many data and too many columns, 1000 columns. Below is a sample first 10 rows:

```
dput(head(df, 10))

structure(list(st_acidente_feriado = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
"VEICULO, NIC", "FACA, FACAO- FERRAMENTA MANUAL SEM FORCA MOTR", 
"ANIMAL VIVO", "MAQUINA AGRICOLA", "SER VIVO, NIC",
"MOTOCICLETA, MOTONETA", "CHAO - SUPERFICIE UTILIZADA PARA SUSTENTAR PE", 
"VEICULO RODOVIARIO MOTORIZADO"), ano_cat = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L),
"Coleta de resíduos não-perigosos",
"Atividades de limpeza não especificadas anteriormente",
"Captação, tratamento e distribuição de água",
"Atividades de atendimento hospitalar",
"Atividades de serviços de complementação diagnóstica e terapêutica"
), dt_acidente = c("26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", 
"26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", "26/04/2013", 
"26/04/2013", "26/04/2013"), st_dia_semana_acidente = c("sex", 
"sex", "sex", "sex", "sex", "sex", "sex", "sex", "sex", "sex"
), ds_emitente_cat = c("Empregador", "Empregador", "Empregador", 
"Empregador", "Empregador", "Empregador", "Empregador", "Empregador", 
"Empregador", "Empregador"), hora_acidente = c("1630", "1940", 
"0400", "1040", "0000", "0900", "1715", "1200", "1400", "0645"
), idade_cat = c(47L, 49L, 47L, 22L, 57L, 40L, 57L, 21L, 35L, 
33L), cd_indica_obito = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N"), nm_municipio = c("São Vicente", "São Paulo", 
"Diadema", "Macapá", "Jaú", "Atibaia", "Curitiba", "São Leopoldo", 
"Porto Velho", "Jundiaí"), nome_uf = c("São Paulo", "São Paulo", 
"São Paulo", "Amapá", "São Paulo", "São Paulo", "Paraná",
"Rondônia", "São Paulo"), ds_natureza_lesao =
"FRATURA", "CORTE, LACERACAO, FERIDA CONTUSA,
"CORTE, LACERACAO, FERIDA CONTUSA, PUNCTURA",
"CORTE, LACERACAO, FERIDA CONTUSA, PUNCTURA",
"LUXACAO", "DISTENSAO, TORCAO"),
"Auxiliar geral de conservação de vias permanentes (exceto trilhos)", 
"Operador de máquinas-ferramenta convencionais",
"Supervisor de exploração agropecuária", "Agente de saúde pública", 
"Zelador de edifício", "Técnico de enfermagem",
"Técnico em radiologia e imagenologia"),
"DEDO", "DEDO", "MAO (exceto punho ou dedos)", "DEDO",
"MAO (exceto punho ou dedos)",
"PE (exceto artelhos)", "OMBRO"),
"Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", "Masculino", 
"Feminino", "Feminino", "Feminino", "Masculino"),
"Típico", "Típico", "Típico", "Típico", "Típico", "Típico", "Trajeto", 
"Típico", "Trajeto"), ds_tipo_local_acidente = c("OUTROS", "EMPREGADORA", 
"EMPREGADORA", "VIA PUBLICA", "EMPRESA PRESTADORA", "VIA PUBLICA", 
"EMPREGADORA", "VIA PUBLICA", "AREA RURAL", "VIA PUBLICA")),
"ds_agente_causador", "ano_cat", "ds_cnae_classe_cat", "dt_acidente", 
"st_dia_semana_acidente", "ds_emitente_cat", "hora_acidente", 
"idade_cat", "cd_indica_obito", "nm_municipio",
"ds_cbo", "ds_parte_corpo_atingida", "cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat", 
"ds_tipo_acidente", "ds_tipo_local_acidente"), spec = structure(list(
cols = structure(list(st_acidente_feriado = structure(list(), 
"collector")), ds_agente_causador = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ano_cat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), ds_cnae_classe_cat = structure(list(), class = 
"collector")), dt_acidente = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), st_dia_semana_acidente = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_emitente_cat = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), hora_acidente = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), idade_cat = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), cd_indica_obito = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), nm_municipio = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), nome_uf = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_natureza_lesao = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_cbo = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_parte_corpo_atingida = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_tipo_acidente = structure(list(), class =
"collector")), ds_tipo_local_acidente = structure(list(), class =
"collector"))), .Names = c("st_acidente_feriado", "ds_agente_causador", 
"ano_cat", "ds_cnae_classe_cat", "dt_acidente", "st_dia_semana_acidente", 
"ds_emitente_cat", "hora_acidente", "idade_cat", "cd_indica_obito", 
"nm_municipio", "nome_uf", "ds_natureza_lesao", "ds_cbo", 
"ds_parte_corpo_atingida", "cd_tipo_sexo_empregado_cat", 
"ds_tipo_acidente", "ds_tipo_local_acidente")), default =
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"),
10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` in the question, like this it's impossible to know what is going on.

Comment: Why do you need to find the name of the column? `column <- df[, index]` should give you the same as `column <- df[, names(df)[index]]`

Comment: copy and paste the output rather than posting a picture

Comment: I do not recreate your issue with test data as `all.equal(df[, name], df$column_1)` returns `TRUE` and both `str()` are the same: atomic character vectors. One column data frame assignment is an atomic vector. Please show where `list` type renders.

Comment: I've already post the image. And I really do not need the name of the column. I did not know that works @C.Braun

Comment: @Parfait when I run "typeof(df[, 1])" it returns "list". But, when I run "typeof(df$column_1)" it returns "character". Why this occurs?

Comment: @Parfait I've just posted the dput returns. I think I understand the problem, but I do not know how to solver it.

Comment: @Parfait See the what I've just posted now.

Comment: @Parfait Actually, this dataframe was produced by another system, that I do not have access and I do not know how it is produced. Your suggestion did not work (as.data.frame(df)). There is any way to get the data inside the list?

Comment: Can you `dput` a few more rows like 5 or 10?

Comment: @Parfait Ja, of course. I've just posted it.

Comment: I'm having a tough time reading that structure. Did you manipulate it anyway after running `dput()`? Try it yourself `df <- structure(...)`.

Comment: The problem is that you've stored "x" as a list. List objects can be stored in a data.frame, but data.frame will never coerce something to a list if it's not already. You need to post-process this output by hand.